# Почему мой код для телеграмм бота не работает?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Пытаюсь постичь телеграмм ботов на python, но не работает функция get_weather. Что я делаю не так?

```
import telebot
import datetime
import requests
from config import telegramToken, owToken
from pprint import pprint

bot = telebot.TeleBot(telegramToken)

print(bot.get_me())

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

if message.text == 'Погода':
  def get_weather(city, owToken):

    code_to_smile = {
      'Clear': "Ясно \U00002600",
      'Clouds': "Облачно \U00002601",
      'Rain': "Дождь \U00002614",
      'Drizzle': "Дождь \U00002614",
      'Thunderstorm': "Гроза \U000026A1",
      'Snow': "Снег \U00001F328",
      'Mist': "Туман \U00001F32B"
    }

    try:
      r = requests.get(
          f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={message.text}&appid= 
      {owToken}&units=metric'
      )
      data = r.json()

      city = data['name']
      cur_weather = data['main']['temp']
      weather_desq = data['weather'][0]['main']
      if weather_desq in code_to_smile:
        wd = code_to_smile[weather_desq]
      else:
        wd = 'Посмотри в окно!'

      humidity = data['main']['humidity']
      wind = data['wind']['speed']
      sunrise_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data['sys']['sunrise'])
      sunset_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data['sys']['sunset'])
      length_of_the_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data['sys']['sunset']) - 
      datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data['sys']['sunrise'])

      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'***{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d 
      %H:%M")}***\n Погода в городе: {city}:\n *Температура: {cur_weather}C° {wd}\n 
      *Влажность: {humidity} %\n *Ветер: {wind}м/с\n *Восход Солнца: 
      {sunrise_timestamp}\n 
      *Закат Солнца: {sunset_timestamp}\n *Продолжительность светового дня: 
      {length_of_the_day} \n Хорошего дня!')

    except:
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Проверьте название города')

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Это вообще запускается?

Comment: ужасов тут гипер много, но самый основной это что вы применяете декоратор на констркуцией `if`. в очередной раз скажу - не знаешь, не делай. если хотите написать что либо нормальное, сначала ознакомьтесь с языком

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После декоратора:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
```

должна быть функция, которую он декорирует, то есть должна идти:

```
def get_weather(city, owToken):
```

Проверка команды должна идти в декораторе:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
```